# How the required Validator can be disabled in Angular Forms for an element?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following scenario:
I have a reactive form in Angular 10, with several elements on which I need to perform various validations and some elements on which I don't need to perform any kind of validation, at all.

```
this.basicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          name: ['', [Validators.required, this.nonEmptyStringValidator]],
          description: [''],
          ///Other form fields
        });

get f() { return this.basicForm.controls; }
```

Both are text input fields. I want that the field "description" to be ignored from any kind of validation.

If I mention it in the above list, it seems that the Required Validator is called by default and my form is forever invalid!

The issue is that if I don't mention it in the formBuilder definition from the above and the field is between the   tags in the template file (HTML), the Angular code that loads the values of some combo boxes from the form will break or the template will miss other Angular elements  (like Angular Hrefs outside the form tags). In other pages, missing a field from this list breaks other Angular code. This, in itself, looks like an Angular bug to me.

The template snippet:

```
<form [formGroup]="basicForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal" >
....

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Description</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control" id="description" required [(ngModel)]="customerEntity2Analyze.description" name="description" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.description.errors }">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.description.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.description.errors.required">Description is required!</div>
        <div *ngIf="f.description.errors.pattern">Description is invalid!</div>
    </div>
</div>
.......
</form>
```

I have tried even with the following:

```
description: null,
description: ['', null],
description: ['', []],
```

I have tried with both syntaxes: simple and the one in which the second value of the configuration array (after the initial form field value) is a configuration object containing 3 properties (**validators**, **asyncValidators**, **updateOn**).
I have even written a custom validator that returns **null** always and use it as the only validator for the "description" field, but no luck!

So, whatever I did, it still renders the form as invalid. It displays the message I put on the presence of **f.description.errors.required**.
How can I do it, or, at least, an work-around?

Comment: You've put `required ` for the element in the template.

Comment: You are right, Misha! That fixed it!